# 2 onClick() methods - one of them gets ignored

Tags: java, android

I have a dialog and I would like to close it, whenever a button has been clicked.

```java
public class Dialog extends DialogFragment {
    @Nullable
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_general, container, false);

        ViewGroup group = (ViewGroup) view.findViewById(R.id.root);
        View v;
        for(int i = 0; i < group.getChildCount(); i++) {
            v = group.getChildAt(i);
            if(v instanceof Button) {
                v.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View view) {
                        getDialog().dismiss();
                    }
                });
            }
        }
        return view;
    }
}
```

Well, the dialog will get closed and so my script seems to work but the problem is the `onClick()` method. In my MainActivity class, I also have another `onClick()` method that will play audio when a button is clicked. So the `onClick()` of the class `Dialog` will simply close the dialog but will not play the audio anymore. I am not sure, but it could be because of `@Override` but even if I remove `@Override`, the audio will still not be played.

How can I play the audio AND close the dialog at the same time?

Comment: Didn't understand your question do you want to play the sound instantly after your dialog is dismiss

Comment: @jayeshjain the sound should be played, before or after dismissing the dialog is not important. What I want is that the other onClick() method is not getting ignored.

Comment: *"that will play audio when **a** button is clicked"* **A** button? Listeners are registered with specific buttons, and every button has it's own list of listeners. Which button(s) is the main activity listener registered with? The dialog button? Some other button(s)?

Comment: @Andreas if you see my code, you will see that there is a loop. So the listener goes to ALL buttons.

Comment: @Reza is your another button which is used for playing is in fragment layouts or some other activity

Comment: @jayeshjain the button is in the same fragment layout. The onClick() of it is in MainActivity class.

Comment: In your code you assign listeners `onClick` in your `DialogFragment` to all children. So wherever you set those listeners previously it will be overriden. You're saying that there is "another button in activity" but you didn't show the sample.

Answer (score 0):

As i undetrstand correctly.
You have 2 onClickListeners, related to 2 different views (lets call them btn1 and btn2). So when you click on btn1 ONLY onClick FOR THIS BTN WILL WORK! It is **logical and normal behavior**.

So. You want to call the onClick from the btn2 too, when you click on btn1. How can you do it? Simply add code from onClick(btn2) to onClick(btn1). It is OK.

If you want to refactor it to not duplicate some code - you can move the code from onClick2 to the method and call it in onClick1 and onClick2.

Comment: You did not understand my issue. Let's say I have only 1 button but I am using 2 onClickListeners for it. The one is for playing a sound and the other is for dismissing the dialog. In my case, only one onClickListeners (dismissing the dialog) works. The other one gets ignored.

Comment: Its normal behavior too. 1 view can have only 1 onClickListener. So your second listener "rewrites" first.

Comment: So, can you tell me how I can close the dialog with my other onClickListener? I have tried it with `Dialog dialog = new Dialog(); dialog.getDialog().dismiss();` but I get the error: *Attempt to invoke virtual method 'android.app.Dialog ch.yourclick.kitt.classes.Dialog.getDialog()' on a null object reference*

Comment: if (getDialog() != null) { getDialog().dismiss(); }

Comment: That will not close the dialog. `getDialog` IS null. That's why I get this error.

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you implement View.OnClickListener in your dialog, like this:

```
public class Dialog extends DialogFragment implements View.OnClickListener {

}
```

And set on click listener passing *`this`* as argument like:

`button1.setOnClickListener(this);`

And in the end you simply override on click

```
@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
    dismiss();
}
```

So it doesn't matter what button you click, it will dismiss the dialog.

Comment: That is just another way to dismiss the dialog but my problem still remains that my other onClick() method is getting ignored. So dismissing the dialog works fine but playing the audio fails.